# How to intercept parent class method by resolving derived class?

Tags: asp.net, unity-container, interception

**Below is my parent class**

```
public class Parent
{
  //This method is intercept-able using **VirtualMethodInterceptor**
  public virtual void Test()
  {
    //Do something
  }
 }
```

**Below is my child class**

```
public class Child:Parent
{
 // This method directly not intercept-able but it calls base.Test() where   Test    is an intercept-able method
 public void Demo(){
   base.Test();
 }
}
```

Now I want to resolve an instance of `Child` class using Unity where `Demo` method will be interceptable. Actually `Demo` method can't be interceptable as because it's not virtual but this method internally invoke `base.Test()` where `Test` is intercept-able. So how to resolve an interceptable instance of `Child` class?

**It doesn't work If I register child class into an unity container like below**

```
    container.RegisterType<Child>(
            new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
            new InterceptionBehavior<Interceptor>()
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done the following:

1) You added the `Interception` extension like this:

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
```

2) The `WillExecute` property of your interception behavior class returns `true`.

3) You obtain the `Child` instance from the container. This can be done directly like this:

```
Child chlid = container.Resolve<Child>();
```

Or by having `Child` as a dependency for some class, and then resolving the object graph that contains this class using the container.

Comment: Though all above are already there in my codes but anyways thanks for your suggestion..

First I want to Resolve child instance which is fine as above. Now, if I call Demo() method using child instance then Test() method should be intercepted as because Demo() internally invoke Test() and Test() is a virtual method so it should be intercepted by VirtualMethodInterceptor behavior

Comment: I tested your scenario and it works in my machine. Can you share a more complete code?